# How to define loss function in Tensorflow [Optimization problem]?

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, regression, loss-function

I'm trying to define a loss function and experiencing difficulties with that. Maybe someone can help me.

I have N data points for `x_i` and `y_i` and I want to fit a straight line (for simplicity) under the following condition:

[image]

i.e. find minimal value of h so that for all points |y_i - f(x_i)| < h. This condition does not refer to **tf.losses.mean_squared_error** or to **LAD** (least absolute deviation), where we minimize the **sum** of the absolute values.

```
tf_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, x.shape)     # input x
tf_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, y.shape)     # input y


l1 = tf.layers.dense(tf_x, 1)          # assume linear activation
output = tf.layers.dense(l1, 1)        # output layer

h = ???
loss = ???
optimizer = tf.train.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

So `sess.run()` should return the predicted line and h value which satisfies the above-mentioned condition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using Tensorflow 1.x API since you mentioned using `tf.placeholder` and `sess.run`, so I have provided the solution using the Tensorflow 1.x API from Tensorflow 2.x. If you want to run in Tensorflow 1.x, just remove `compat.v1`.

```
    tf_x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name='x')  # input x
    tf_y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name='y')  # input y
    h = tf.Variable(0.0, name='h')

    l1 = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(tf_x, 1, name='layer_1')  # assume linear activation
    output = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(l1, 1, name='output')  # output layer
    loss = tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(tf_y - output)) + tf.abs((h - tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(tf_y - output))))
    optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(loss)
    init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
    variables = tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables()

    x = np.expand_dims(np.array([5.0, 5.0], dtype=np.float32), axis=-1)
    y = np.expand_dims(np.array([2.0, 3.0], dtype=np.float32), axis=-1)

    with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)

        for step in range(1000):
            _, val = sess.run([optimizer, loss],
                              feed_dict={tf_x: x, tf_y: y})
            prediction = sess.run(output, feed_dict={'x:0': x})
            print(prediction)
            if step % 5 == 0:
                print("step: {}, loss: {}".format(step, val))
            print([{variable.name: sess.run(variable)} for variable in variables])
```

I have included some print statements to assist with observing the training process. The loss function is a bit weird looking because of the problem statement - we're learning both the function `f(x)` which approximates `y` and the residual error `h`. I used dummy inputs to verify the functionality of the model - by providing two 5's with an output of 2 and 3, the model is forced to compromise and converge around predicting 2.5. From the last steps:

```
step: 990, loss: 0.6000000238418579
[{'h:0': 0.5}, {'layer_1/kernel:0': array([[0.04334712]], dtype=float32)}, {'layer_1/bias:0': array([-0.2167356], dtype=float32)}, {'output/kernel:0': array([[-1.0096708e-09]], dtype=float32)}, {'output/bias:0': array([2.4000003], dtype=float32)}]
[[2.6000004]
 [2.6000004]]
[{'h:0': 0.6}, {'layer_1/kernel:0': array([[0.04334712]], dtype=float32)}, {'layer_1/bias:0': array([-0.2167356], dtype=float32)}, {'output/kernel:0': array([[-1.0096708e-09]], dtype=float32)}, {'output/bias:0': array([2.6000004], dtype=float32)}]
[[2.4000003]
 [2.4000003]]
[{'h:0': 0.70000005}, {'layer_1/kernel:0': array([[0.04334712]], dtype=float32)}, {'layer_1/bias:0': array([-0.2167356], dtype=float32)}, {'output/kernel:0': array([[-1.0096708e-09]], dtype=float32)}, {'output/bias:0': array([2.4000003], dtype=float32)}]
[[2.4000003]
 [2.4000003]]
[{'h:0': 0.6}, {'layer_1/kernel:0': array([[0.04334712]], dtype=float32)}, {'layer_1/bias:0': array([-0.2167356], dtype=float32)}, {'output/kernel:0': array([[-1.0096708e-09]], dtype=float32)}, {'output/bias:0': array([2.4000003], dtype=float32)}]
[[2.4000003]
 [2.4000003]]
[{'h:0': 0.5}, {'layer_1/kernel:0': array([[0.04334712]], dtype=float32)}, {'layer_1/bias:0': array([-0.2167356], dtype=float32)}, {'output/kernel:0': array([[-1.0096708e-09]], dtype=float32)}, {'output/bias:0': array([2.4000003], dtype=float32)}]
[[2.6000004]
 [2.6000004]]
step: 995, loss: 0.6999993324279785
[{'h:0': 0.6}, {'layer_1/kernel:0': array([[0.04334712]], dtype=float32)}, {'layer_1/bias:0': array([-0.2167356], dtype=float32)}, {'output/kernel:0': array([[-1.0096708e-09]], dtype=float32)}, {'output/bias:0': array([2.6000004], dtype=float32)}]
[[2.4000003]
 [2.4000003]]
[{'h:0': 0.70000005}, {'layer_1/kernel:0': array([[0.04334712]], dtype=float32)}, {'layer_1/bias:0': array([-0.2167356], dtype=float32)}, {'output/kernel:0': array([[-1.0096708e-09]], dtype=float32)}, {'output/bias:0': array([2.4000003], dtype=float32)}]
[[2.4000003]
 [2.4000003]]
[{'h:0': 0.6}, {'layer_1/kernel:0': array([[0.04334712]], dtype=float32)}, {'layer_1/bias:0': array([-0.2167356], dtype=float32)}, {'output/kernel:0': array([[-1.0096708e-09]], dtype=float32)}, {'output/bias:0': array([2.4000003], dtype=float32)}]
[[2.4000003]
 [2.4000003]]
[{'h:0': 0.5}, {'layer_1/kernel:0': array([[0.04334712]], dtype=float32)}, {'layer_1/bias:0': array([-0.2167356], dtype=float32)}, {'output/kernel:0': array([[-1.0096708e-09]], dtype=float32)}, {'output/bias:0': array([2.4000003], dtype=float32)}]
[[2.6000004]
 [2.6000004]]
[{'h:0': 0.6}, {'layer_1/kernel:0': array([[0.04334712]], dtype=float32)}, {'layer_1/bias:0': array([-0.2167356], dtype=float32)}, {'output/kernel:0': array([[-1.0096708e-09]], dtype=float32)}, {'output/bias:0': array([2.6000004], dtype=float32)}]
```

Notice the model predicts 2.4-2.6 for the inputs and for `h`, the estimate is between 0.5-0.7, which is close to the actual residual errors (0.4-0.6). The behavior may change with real data - specifically, with real data there may not be duplicate inputs with different outputs, which is confusing for a model. To sanity check, we can run again with the same outputs, but change the input to 7:

```
step: 995, loss: 1.9000002145767212
[{'h:0': 1.8000002}, {'layer_1/kernel:0': array([[0.60248166]], dtype=float32)}, {'layer_1/bias:0': array([0.21199825], dtype=float32)}, {'output/kernel:0': array([[1.0599916]], dtype=float32)}, {'output/bias:0': array([0.2], dtype=float32)}]
[[-0.767429 ]
 [-1.0744007]]
[{'h:0': 1.9000002}, {'layer_1/kernel:0': array([[-0.88150656]], dtype=float32)}, {'layer_1/bias:0': array([-6.8724134e-08], dtype=float32)}, {'output/kernel:0': array([[0.1741176]], dtype=float32)}, {'output/bias:0': array([0.], dtype=float32)}]
[[3.543093]
 [4.895095]]
[{'h:0': 2.0000002}, {'layer_1/kernel:0': array([[-0.6377419]], dtype=float32)}, {'layer_1/bias:0': array([0.03482345], dtype=float32)}, {'output/kernel:0': array([[-1.0599916]], dtype=float32)}, {'output/bias:0': array([0.2], dtype=float32)}]
[[3.543093]
 [4.895095]]
[{'h:0': 1.9000002}, {'layer_1/kernel:0': array([[-0.6377419]], dtype=float32)}, {'layer_1/bias:0': array([0.03482345], dtype=float32)}, {'output/kernel:0': array([[-1.0599916]], dtype=float32)}, {'output/bias:0': array([0.2], dtype=float32)}]
[[3.543093]
 [4.895095]]
[{'h:0': 1.8000002}, {'layer_1/kernel:0': array([[-0.6377419]], dtype=float32)}, {'layer_1/bias:0': array([0.03482345], dtype=float32)}, {'output/kernel:0': array([[-1.0599916]], dtype=float32)}, {'output/bias:0': array([0.2], dtype=float32)}]
```

It's fairly accurate, as the residual error is about 2.1 (7 - 4.89) and `h` is output as 1.8.

It's worth noting some additional pieces may be required for this loss function - for example, bounding `output` since it's linear and can go to infinity (which the model may do to minimize the loss -  `tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(tf_y - output))` means that `output` being infinity results in a negative infinity loss) - but this should be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but there is a scipy.optimize package, which provides several commonly used optimization algorithms. Here is a link to the documentation.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

I've been using this a lot recently, and the results are fantastic!

Comment: Thanks for this. I agree with you that the scipy.optimize is great tool and there is no doubt it can handle such task. However I'm trying to solve this problem via Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the L-inf norm of the delta between y_true and y_pred for each datapoint. The L-inf norm only calculates loss from the maximum diverging data point. If you could optimize for that, you'd find the minimum h.

Of course, L-inf is not differentiable since it's just a mathematical way to express "max". So you can approximate it with an Ln norm where n is large. You can grid search for an n that stays numerically stable and try other tricks like gradient clipping.

Also, I suspect that if you approximate L-inf using a schedule of losses, first L2, you can gradually increase the n to L3, L4, L5, etc., to help the training process.